# Oracle Select vs Insert/Select (11GR2)

Tags: oracle, optimization, oracle11g, query-optimization

So, I'm in the process of writing a process that will populate a table using about 10 different selects.  As part of the process I've picked up a few things, however I'm facing some inconsistent behaviour at times when performing an INSERT/SELECT.   When I run the select query alone, I get results back within 10 seconds (after I flush buffer cache and shared_pool), but at soon as I tag on the insert portion, takes over 10 min...

Here's what I'm doing after I clear the table... Added the "Append" hint on insert which appeared to have helped quite a bit earlier this week, but now it's back to taking longer than usual, but only when performing the insert!!

```
--// Disable GL_JLOG_DETAILS INDEXES
Execute immediate 'alter index IDX_GLDTL1 unusable';
Execute immediate 'alter index IDX_GLDTL2 unusable';


--// SECTION 1
INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL(6) */ INTO GL_JLOG_DETAILS ( MAT_SECTION    
                                                  ,JLOG_KEY        
                                                  ,SRC_CD          
                                                  ,SRC_KEY         
                                                  ,CASE_KEY        
                                                  ,CASE_MBR_KEY    
                                                  ,UNALLOC_ACCT_CD 
                                                  ,FDRT_KEY        
                                                  ,FDRT_TR_CD      
                                                  ,TR_CD           
                                                  ,TR_REF_NO       
                                                  ,STAT_CD         
                                                  ,FD_DESC_ID      
                                                  ,FD_NO           
                                                  ,FD_TYP_CD       
                                                  ,BKT_NO          
                                                  ,RVSL_CD         
                                                  ,CO_CD           
                                                  ,BEN_RPT_TYP_CD  
                                                  ,DB_CR_CD        
                                                  ,ACCT_NO         
                                                  ,SUB_ACCT_NO     
                                                  ,JRNL_AMT        
                                                  ,TDTL_AMT        
                                                  ,RVSL_ERROR      
                                                  ,RVSL_SAME_DAY   
                                                  ,TDTL_REF_KEY)    
          ---// SECTION 1 //--------
          Select  /*+ USE_NL(TMAP,TMOV,ACCT,SBNT,BNTP,FDRT) */ '1' MAT_SECTION,
           JLOG.JLOG_KEY,
           JLOG.SRC_CD,
           TDTL.TDTL_KEY AS SRC_KEY,
           TDTL.CASE_KEY,
           TDTL.CASE_MBR_KEY,
           TDTL.UNALLOC_ACCT_CD,
           TDTL.FDRT_KEY,
           FDRT.TR_CD FDRT_TR_CD,
           TDTL.TR_CD,
           TDTL.TR_REF_NO,
           TDTL.STAT_CD,
           TDTL.FD_DESC_ID,
           TDTL.FD_NO,
           FDDC.FD_TYP_CD,
           TDTL.BKT_NO,
           JLOG.RVSL_CD,
           BNTP.CO_CD,
           SBNT.BEN_RPT_TYP_CD,
           JLOG.DB_CR_CD,
           ACCT.ACCT_NO,
           ACCT.SUB_ACCT_NO,
           JLOG.JRNL_AMT,
           ABS (TDTL.AMT) AS TDTL_AMT,
           CASE
              WHEN TDTL.PROC_DT < TDTL.RVSL_CYC_DT AND TDTL.ORIG_INBS_KEY IS NULL
              THEN
                 1
              ELSE
                 0
             END  RVSL_ERROR,
           CASE
              WHEN  TDTL.PROC_DT = TDTL.RVSL_CYC_DT  AND NOT TDTL.TR_CD IN ('3002','3004','1501','1502','1503','1504','1505')
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
           END  RVSL_SAME_DAY,
           TDTL.REF_KEY TDTL_REF_KEY
          from GL_JOURNAL_LOGS JLOG, 
               Transact_Details TDTL, 
               FUND_DESC FDDC, 
               FD_RATES FDRT, 
               BEN_TYPES BNTP, 
               SYS_BEN_TYPES SBNT, 
               LEDGER_ACCOUNTS ACCT, 
               TRANS_MAP_OVRD TMOV, 
               TRANSACTION_MAP TMAP 
           WHERE JLOG.JRNL_CD = '0' 
           AND JLOG.SRC_CD = '2' 
           AND JLOG.MKEY_FD_NUM <> 0 
           AND NVL(JLOG.TMOV_KEY, -1) > 0 
           AND NVL(JLOG.ORIG_SCAT_KEY, 1) = 1 
           AND JLOG.Scat_key = TDTL.SCAT_KEY 
           AND JLOG.TR_CD = TDTL.TR_CD 
           AND JLOG.CASE_KEY = TDTL.CASE_KEY 
           AND JLOG.TR_REF_NO = TDTL.TR_REF_NO 
           AND JLOG.ACCT_KEY = ACCT.ACCT_KEY 
           AND JLOG.TMOV_KEY = TMOV.TMOV_KEY 
           AND NVL(TDTL.ORIG_SCAT_KEY, 1) = 1 
           AND TDTL.STAT_CD <> '4' 
           AND TDTL.FD_DESC_ID = FDDC.FD_DESC_ID 
           AND TDTL.FDRT_KEY = FDRT.FDRT_KEY 
           AND BNTP.BNTP_KEY = FDRT.BNTP_KEY 
           AND BNTP.SBNT_KEY  (+) = SBNT.SBNT_KEY 
           AND TMOV.TMAP_KEY = TMAP.TMAP_KEY 
           AND TMOV.CO_CD = BNTP.CO_CD 
           AND DECODE(FDDC.MKEY_FD_NUM, NULL, TMAP.MKEY_FD_NUM, FDDC.MKEY_FD_NUM) = TMAP.MKEY_FD_NUM;
```

Any tips / advice would be greatly appreciated!

Explain Plan

```
Plan hash value: 4157721082

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT                       |                  |     1 |   212 |  1596   (1)| 00:00:20 |
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT                        | GL_JLOG_DETAILS  |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                         |                  |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                        |                  |     1 |   212 |  1596   (1)| 00:00:20 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                       |                  |     1 |   195 |  1595   (1)| 00:00:20 |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                      |                  |     1 |   190 |  1594   (1)| 00:00:20 |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                     |                  |    12 |  2172 |  1582   (1)| 00:00:19 |
|*  7 |        HASH JOIN                       |                  |    12 |  2004 |  1570   (1)| 00:00:19 |
|   8 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL              | FUND_DESC        |   168 |  1176 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |         NESTED LOOPS                   |                  |       |       |            |          |
|  10 |          NESTED LOOPS                  |                  |   257 | 41120 |  1566   (1)| 00:00:19 |
|  11 |           NESTED LOOPS                 |                  |   257 | 22359 |   537   (0)| 00:00:07 |
|  12 |            NESTED LOOPS                |                  |   257 | 20817 |   280   (0)| 00:00:04 |
|* 13 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| GL_JOURNAL_LOGS  |   257 | 18504 |    23   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_ORIGSCATKEY  |   690 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TRANS_MAP_OVRD   |     1 |     9 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | TMOV_PK          |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | TRANSACTION_MAP  |     1 |     6 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | TMAP_PK          |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN             | IX_AML8890       |     3 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | TRANSACT_DETAILS |     1 |    73 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | FD_RATES         |     1 |    14 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | FDRT_PK          |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 23 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | BEN_TYPES        |     1 |     9 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | BNTP_PK          |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  25 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | SYS_BEN_TYPES    |     1 |     5 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 26 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | SBNT_PK          |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 27 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | ACCT_PK          |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  28 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | LEDGER_ACCOUNTS  |     1 |    17 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   7 - access("TDTL"."FD_DESC_ID"="FDDC"."FD_DESC_ID")
       filter("TMAP"."MKEY_FD_NUM"=DECODE(TO_CHAR("FDDC"."MKEY_FD_NUM"),NULL,"TMAP"."MKEY_FD_NUM","
              FDDC"."MKEY_FD_NUM"))
  13 - filter("JLOG"."TMOV_KEY" IS NOT NULL AND "JLOG"."SRC_CD"='2' AND "JLOG"."MKEY_FD_NUM"<>0 
              AND NVL("TMOV_KEY",(-1))>0 AND "JLOG"."JRNL_CD"='0')
  14 - access(NVL("ORIG_SCAT_KEY",1)=1)
  16 - access("JLOG"."TMOV_KEY"="TMOV"."TMOV_KEY")
  18 - access("TMOV"."TMAP_KEY"="TMAP"."TMAP_KEY")
  19 - access("JLOG"."SCAT_KEY"="TDTL"."SCAT_KEY" AND "JLOG"."CASE_KEY"="TDTL"."CASE_KEY")
       filter("TDTL"."FD_DESC_ID" IS NOT NULL AND "TDTL"."STAT_CD"<>'4' AND 
              "JLOG"."CASE_KEY"="TDTL"."CASE_KEY")
  20 - filter("TDTL"."FDRT_KEY" IS NOT NULL AND NVL("TDTL"."ORIG_SCAT_KEY",1)=1 AND 
              "JLOG"."TR_CD"="TDTL"."TR_CD" AND "JLOG"."TR_REF_NO"="TDTL"."TR_REF_NO")
  22 - access("TDTL"."FDRT_KEY"="FDRT"."FDRT_KEY")
  23 - filter("TMOV"."CO_CD"="BNTP"."CO_CD")
  24 - access("BNTP"."BNTP_KEY"="FDRT"."BNTP_KEY")
  26 - access("BNTP"."SBNT_KEY"="SBNT"."SBNT_KEY")
  27 - access("JLOG"."ACCT_KEY"="ACCT"."ACCT_KEY")
```

Comment: are you sure that the query takes 10 seconds? if you are using SQL Developer it will only show you the first x records (x is usually 50); so it may take 10 seconds to show you the top x records and not the yyxx (which count be >>) records.  I see you turn off two indexes, are there any more?  Are there any triggers that fire on insert on the table (that alone can KILL performance). Try a CTAS (Create Table as Select) and see the performance

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm running the select in TOAD. The select time fluctuates, but on every try I'm still getting results back under 20 seconds which pulls the first 500 rows, so at that rate, given the fact I only have a few thousand records to pull, should still be fairly quick.  I disabled the indexes on insert and then rebuild at the end of the process.  I read that this could hinder performance on insert so rendering your indexes unusable for the insert was considered "good practice".... there are no triggers or constraints on the destination table at all.

Comment: Please show us the execution plan (of the whole INSERT statement)

Comment: Explain plan added to the original post

Comment: If the query is fast but the insert is slow then you may need to look at the insert portion rather than the plan. Is there any other activity on the table that could be causing contention? Is the the tablespace continuously extending? Are you waiting for redo logs to roll? (check your alert log) If you are only doing a few thousand rows, these kinds of things shouldn't really be an issue, but might give you another idea where to look.

Comment: @Glenn - Unless the "parallelism" is somehow causing other activity, it shouldn't be seeing any other action while doing that insert.  I even commit after each insert in case the population process at some other point in the proc.  I've disabled logging on the tablespace in question to see whether it would have any type of impact, it's strange... I'll see if I can't find any other log or indication of what's happening... makes no sense!

Comment: To further isolate the problem, if permissible in your environment, try putting the results of your query into a temporary table (or populate a temporary table with bogus records). Then try the insert from the temporary table (you don't have to commit). If the insert from the temporary table is just as slow, then you know it does not seem to have anything to do with the subquery.

Comment: Are you performing a `TRUNCATE` on the table before you load it? I think the APPEND hint causes a direct load operation, which will allocate and format new blocks beyond the current high water mark on the table. And all those changes need to be written to the redo log, so there may be an issue with performance of checkpoints, and log archiving, if database is in archive log mode.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems with "Direct path" load a.k.a. /*+ APPEND */.

Firstly, it isn't necessarily faster in general. It does a direct path load to disk - bypassing the buffer cache. In many cases - especially with smaller sets of data - where the direct path load to disk would be slower than a conventional path load into the cache.

Second, DPL works above the high watermark of the table which means it does not re-use the space. So unless you `TRUNCATE` the whole table every time, it probably isn't gonna be necessarily faster.

Third, only one seesion/user can DPL on to a table at a time. That may cause concurrency issues, here all the modifications will become serialized (like a serial circuit, rather than a parallel circuit). No insert/update/delete or merge into this table will be allowed until the transaction that direct paths, commits.

Lastly, the indexes of your table in question matters. It is pretty difficult to say without looking at the data as of what kind of index will be appropriate and on which columns. Try a combination of Local and global bitmap indexes, but be careful while chosing the columns. Making an index 'unusable' is not a good idea in general, there is a purpose why it was created and altering it almost conflicts to its immediate interests.

To start with, remove all hints, try indexing. and iff it is a reloadable table then truncate it prior to every load.